# Terraform Macbook M1 AWS

Tags: bash, terraform, devops, arm64

issue

```
Error: Incompatible provider version
│ 
│ Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0 does not have a
│ package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.
│ 
│ Provider releases are separate from Terraform CLI releases, so not all
│ providers are available for all platforms. Other versions of this provider
│ may have different platforms supported.
```

I followed this guide ran into issue doing last steps.

```
Then copy from $GOPATH/bin/terraform-provider-aws to:

~/.terraform.d/plugins/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/3.22.0/dar
```

what is $GOPATH ? I also ran into issue doing `$make build`

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27257#issuecomment-754777716

Answer (score 2):

I made a  docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  terraform:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: hashicorp/terraform:0.12.21
    volumes:
      - .:/infra
    working_dir: /infra
```

ran the docker-compose.yml with

```
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml run --rm terraform apply
```

works like a charm (:

Answer (score 1):

`template_file` [has been deprecated](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs) and you can safely replace it with [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile). The API is a bit different but the end result is about the same. (The new API supports `Darwin ARM64` of course)